# ts of page called but html not visible in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

an array created as

```
this.pages = {'HomePage':HomePage}
```

code used to open page

```
 openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    console.log(page.component);
    this.nav.setRoot(this.pages[page.component]);
  }
```

By calling open page method as

```
openpage('HomePage');
```

it calls the ts file of the home page and do all its functions but it donot display its html contetnts.

Comment: can you share exact format of your current this.pages - it is an object here and not array.

Comment: And can you share more context as to what you mean by dynamic generation of string as page names?

Comment: I have to display options depends on some conditions that's why created an array based on condition for my menu and display it using ngfor in ion-item and now the options page names are in string but it is not accessible in setroot

Answer (score 1):

Your array does not contain any key-value pair as **component**. You can use the page name directly, as follows:

```
openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    console.log(page);
    this.nav.setRoot(page[page]);
}
```

**Another Solution:**
 If you want component as one key-value pair and then redirection change can use the following thing:

```
this.pages = [
      { title: 'HomePage', component: 'HomePage' }
];
```

And then redirect using the following method:

```
openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
```

HTML as follows:

```
<button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
</button>
```

Comment: I was using this before but i have dynamic page names which are stored as strings so i was required to bind those page names as components were required that's why used this please tell me how can i bind those two values in an array and use those

Comment: I used array as this.pages = [
      { title: 'HomePage', component: 'HomePage' }
]; but i have to use open page method as i already using openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    console.log(page.component);
    this.nav.setRoot(this.pages[page.component]);
  } as i have page as an array that contains data as {component:'HomePage',val1:'Value1'} i have to use this component name to fetch page name from pages array

Comment: openPage(page) {
    var result = this.pages.find(obj => {
      return obj.title === page
    })
    this.nav.setRoot(result.component);
  } used this code and this is giving me the same  component as required by the setroot but page is not still visible but its ts is called

Comment: ƒ AnnexurePage(navCtrl, navParams, modalCtrl, user) {
        this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
        this.navParams = navParams;
        this.modalCtrl = modalCtrl;
        this.user = user;
got this message in console when print result.component

Comment: Is this possible to use navpush instead of setroot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand your use case (with dynamic page naming), but you could in theory leverage js Map object which is (should be) more suitable for such mapping:

```
// init map (as string to page map):
pages: Map<string, any> = new Map([['HomePage', HomePage ],['AboutPage', AboutPage]])

// use open page this way:
openPage(page) {
    // here page.component returns a string with a page name:
    console.log(page.component);
    let component = this.pages.get(page.component)
    this.nav.setRoot(component);
}
```

Example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ywn7zb

Comment: trying to use your method as in declaration before constructor used pages: Map<string, Component> in Constructor let source = [['HomePage', HomePage ],['AboutPage', AboutPage]]
this.pages  = new Map(source); on using this it gives me syntax error on new map(source)

Comment: also tried to use var source:Array<{title: string, component: any}> = [{title:'CashbreakPage',component: CashbreakPage },{title:'VoucherPage', component:VoucherPage}];this.pages  = source.map((source)=>source.title,source.component); getting syntax error on source.component Property component doesnot exist on type {title:string,component:any}[]

Comment: Ok sorry ill fix that fir you in a bit

Comment: NavPush will give back button but i need menu on each page

Comment: Trying to use it from Split Pane and using app.component.ts for the whole code but it do not display any html layout while running

Comment: In app.component.ts if i add public nav : NavController in constructor it stop showing menu in split pane you can check it in example link above

Comment: but you see you have errors? you can't inject NavController into the app.component.ts you have to use reference from template there. here is fixed forked code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rrpojw

Comment: It gives console message ƒ ContactPage()
 name: "ContactPage"
 __proto__: Function in stackblitz but ƒ ContactPage(navCtrl, navParams, user, modalCtrl, vwCtrl) {
        this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
        this.navParams = navParams;
        this.user = user;
        this.modalCtrl = modalCtrl;
in my application which is coded using visual studio code It worked fine in stackblitz but not in my application